# QWebView does not display Monospace fonts

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebkit, qwebview

I try the simplest example of PyQt5 QWebView that I could find and try to display a Monospace font in HTML.
QWebView is quite powerful, all I want to do works, except the Monospace font.

Here is the example code:
`

````
#! /usr/bin/python3
#coding: latin-1

"""
https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/webkit/fancybrowser/fancybrowser.py
"""

import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage, QWebView
#from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import QWebEngineSettings

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello')
        self.resize(768, 576)

        self.view = QWebView(self)

        fpath = os.path.abspath("test.html")
        self.view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fpath))
        self.view.loadFinished.connect(self.loaded)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def loaded(self):
        print("Loaded")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

win = MyWidget()
win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```
````

Here is the test.html that I try and that works in firefox for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p style="font-family:'Courier New'">This is another paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody got a hint what I need to do to use any Monospace font?

I run PyQt5 on Linux, OpenSuse 15.3.

Please find the screenshots showing the behavior (Ok in Firefox, Ok in Chrome, NOT Ok in PyQt5 WebView):
[image]
The font in the second paragraph is as expected.

[image]
The font in the second paragraph is as expected.

[image]
The font in the second paragraph is incorrect.

Comment: Excuse the ignorance, but in your case where have you set the monospace font? What is the monospace font? Are script.js and vs.css relevant? If they are not then could you remove it?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I removed the references to script.js and vs.css.  They were irrelevant and confusing.  I set the font as style of the second paragraph explicitly by style=font-family...

Comment: Could you show an image that proves the error?